# Is there any way to include the literal text of another file?

Tags: input, include

From what I have read, input processes text and includes commands found, and include can't be used in the preamble for some reason (correct me if I'm wrong). I just want a command that replaces itself with the literal text of the referenced file, and does absolutely nothing else. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can use `\input` for literal text in the document of course, but not in the preamble. (Or better: Use `\InputFileIfExists{filename}{true}{false}`

Comment: So input is literal in the body? And you are not aware of something that is always literal?

Comment: Well, it depends under `literal` actual. Pure text? No formatting?

Comment: what do you mean by "literal" ? `\input{file}` is just like copying the contents of the file to that point but that means any tex commands in `file` are executed. If you want to typeset the contents of a file verbatim, treating any tex commands as pure text you want `\verbatiminput` from the verbatim package (or fancier version such a listings or minted)

Comment: By literal, I mean there would never be any difference in the output file between: 1. using the command, say myInclude{file.tex}, or 2. deleting "myInclude{file.tex}" and pasting into the text editor the full contents of that file, and then compiling.

Comment: that's `\input` (apart from some special rules about command arguments not going past the end of the file}

Comment: So there is no option without those special rules for \input?

Comment: @KyleStewart do you really want to be able to have `\section{ab` at the end of one file and  `cd}`  in the main file and have it typeset as `\section{abcd}` ?

Comment: @David Carlisle, yes, I understand the potential issues, but I would like that. It would be error prone in some situations, but it would be ideal for my way of doing things.

Comment: concatenate the files with perl or python or somesuch before processing with TeX in that case.

Comment: I was afraid that was the only way, I just wanted to see if there was an alternative from within tex.

Comment: `\input` handles all reasonable use cases:-)  the restriction on unmatched braces is no different to the restriction that you can not store `\section{ab` as the replacement text of `\def` or `\newcommand`

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `\include` in the preamble since it always issues a `\clearpage` -- which is 'typesetting' effectively.

`\input{}` is possible for literal text content in the document body without formatting, but the usual empty lines etc. are regarded as start of new paragraphs.

Another way is `\lstinputlisting{filename}` from `listings` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}


\begin{document}
\InputIfFileExists{literalinput.txt}{}{}%

Or

\lstinputlisting{literalinput.txt} % Verbatim loading of text.
\end{document}
```

The file `literalinput.txt` just contains

```
This is meant

for

the literal input of text.
```

[image]

Comment: +1 -- this comment is more for OP: I would prefer simpler things than `listings` for non-code applications. More information can be found on the [UK TeX FAQ](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-verbfile.html).

Comment: @SeanAllred: `fancyvrb`, for example?

Comment: If I understand correctly, your solution inputs the text literally into the output file (correct me if I'm wrong). I didn't know how to do that, so I appreciate it. However, I want to input literally into the tex file before compilation.

Comment: @KyleStewart no one would have guessed that from your question though (although you clarified in comments) the question would have been much clearer if you had provided example input (preferably complete testable document) and required output.